# Are Gtk 3.10 widgets backwards compatible?

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm, glade

*I'm not sure if this question should be on the Ubuntu site or here. I'm posting it here because it's about programming, but maybe it should be migrated.*

I use gtkmm with the defualt GCC tool chain on Ubuntu, and I just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS, which uses GTK+ 3.10 .

I have Glade project file that uses `Gtk::TextEntry` and `Gtk::SpinButton` widgets. When I opened the project in Glade after upgrading from 12.04 LTS, I got this message when I tried to save the Glade file. (I didn't save the file - I stuck with the old one so I wouldn't corrupt something.)

```
[window1:frame1:box1:layout1:spinbutton3] Property 'Placeholder text' of object class 'Text Entry' was introduced in gtk+ 3.2. ]
```

When I build and run the C++ project some widgets aren't rendered correctly (SpinEdit up/down button are missing and the labels I put up there are skewed in position):

[image]

This was all working fine before the upgrade.

In Synaptic I see that I now have libgtk-3-0 and libgtk-3-0-dev installed and no further updates are available.

Is there a compatibility issue with 3.2 widgets when running 3.10? Is the problem with Glade? Did I just do something wrong that 3.10 is catching but 3.2 did not? Why is this happening? How can I fix it? I'm confused as to what/where the problem is.

Comment: How is the position of those labels specified exactly? It looks to me like you are simply using a broken layout, and things are not positioned and sized as they should be. Also, the spin button up/down buttons are not missing. That's what the "-" and "+" on the right side of the spin buttons are for.

Comment: @dobey - _That's what the "-" and "+"..._ : They changed the buttons? There used to be nice little glyphs for up/down. I set the position of the labels in Glade->Packing x/y. If they changed the look of the buttons then I'll just assume the layout is broken so the labels are misplaced and something either didn't bother 3.2 or was working differently in 3.2.

Comment: Yes, the theme changed. I'm not sure if it's due to GTK+ itself, or the theme, that the buttons are moved like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use X/Y positioning to create layouts in GTK+. GTK+ is based on the box model. You should be using GtkGrid to lay those widgets out in a grid, so that the labels and spin buttons are in a Grid. Specifying X/Y positioning will lead to potential issues exactly like you are seeing, if the user changes their font size, or the theme changes, or other such things.

Comment: Why is Glade giving me that error message? Any idea? If 3.10 supports 'Placeholder text' why is Glade complaining? I just updated Glade - but I already have the latest version in the regular repositories. Apt didn't do anything.

Comment: I don't know why Glade is complaining about that. I don't see any evidence in your screenshot that any placeholder text is being used, either. I would just get rid of placeholder text properties, as you've got separate labels anyway. If you're setting the property to a string, not numbers, it may be part of the problem, since spinbuttons can only have numbers entered in them.

Comment: Yes, I got rid of them in the Glade file. Done. I thought it was related to the weirdness I was seeing when I ran the app, but apparently not.